# Bibliography as own bookmark

Tags: bibliographies, bookmarks

In my pdf the bibliography is shown as a section from appendix but I would like to have a own bookmark for it.

The bookmark looks like following.

```
...
Chapter D
Chapter E
Appendix
    Appendix A
    Appendix C
    Appendix D
    ...
    Bibliography
```

How could use the bibliography in a own bookmark at the end? Like this:

```
...
Chapter D
Chapter E
Appendix
    Appendix A
    Appendix C
    Appendix D
    ...
Bibliography
```

I use following in my TeX document.

```
% Appendix
\appendix
\addpart{\appendixname}
\input{Appendix/A_Requirements}
\input{Appendix/B_Analysis}
\input{Appendix/C_Feature}
\input{Appendix/D_Project}

% Bibliography
\printbibliography
```

**Edit**

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,twoside=false,DIV10,chapterprefix,headsepline=true,index=totoc,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc,appendixprefix=true]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{chngcntr} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[german]{cleveref}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\bibliography{Bibliography/Bibliography}

\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\input{Component/Settings}

% Author informations

% Front
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\input{Component/Titlepage}
\input{Component/Declaration-Of-Authorship}
\input{Component/Abstract}

\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings

\chapter{Acronym} 
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{...}{...}
\end{acronym}

% Content
\mainmatter
\input{...}


% Appendix
\appendix
\addpart{\appendixname}
\input{Appendix/...}
\input{Appendix/...}
\input{Appendix/...}
\input{Appendix/...}

% Bibliography
\backmatter
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Package `bookmark` provides option `startatroot` for this purpose. If set before the bibliography, the bookmark for the bibliography is set at top level, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[...]{scrbook}
...
\usepackage[...]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{open,numbered}% I like numbered bookmarks
...
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
...
\mainmatter
...
\backmatter
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\printbibliography
...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because there is an [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) missing in your question I can only guess.

I would insert the macro `\backmatter` before your `\printbibliography`.  Of course you should use documentclass `book` or `scrbook` and you should load package `hyperref`. Something like this:

```
\documentclass[%
 ,paper=a4           % papersize
 ,fontsize=12pt      % 
 ,bibliography=totoc %
]{scrbook}           % scrbook

\usepackage{hyperref} %


\begin{document}  

\frontmatter          % first part of book
\maketitle            % Title of the book/thesis
\tableofcontents      % 
\listoffigures        % 
\listoftables         % 

\mainmatter           % main part of book
\include{introduction}  % and so on ...

\appendix
\include{tables}      % first part of appendix 

\backmatter           % bibliography, index
%\bibliography{bibfile} % bibliography with bibtex
\printbibliography      % bibliography with biblatex
\printindex            % index

\end{document}
```

If you want an better advice you should please add an MWE.

Comment: Please see my **Edit**. I added my structure which is not working correctly. Because of the `input`, I cannot add a complete working example. I hope that help to figure out the problem. I cannot use `bibliography` in that way.

Comment: I had `\backmatter` befor `printbibliography` but does not work for me. @heiko-oberdiek solutions works very well. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Yea, maybe some wild settings :). But thanks alot!